# Creating a custom content query web part

Tags: content-query-web-part, parameter

The basic gist is that I would like to create a content query web part that shows the 10 most recent documents in the project provided by the URL parameter.

I currently have it set up such that all of my CQWPs are able to be filtered by the parameter, but i can't for the life of me figure out how to load the right document library.

For example:
If i have "project 1" and "project 2", i will then have two document libraries, one for each: dl_project 1 and dl_project2. Now, if i pass in the parameter for project1, i would like the 10 most recent documents either modified or created by the current user. That way when the user visits a project page, it loads the documents they were working on for that project. Ideas?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? If Online or 2013, you could (potentially) simplify this by using a Content Search Web Part.

Comment: sharepoint online

Comment: For the Content Search web part using a URL parameter, look at this article [Content Search Web Part with Query String](https://wonderlaura.com/2015/02/19/content-search-web-part-with-query-string/). You can narrow your result search by focusing on the Content Type (assuming the same for each project) and/or limiting the Path to a specific site.